# How to keep table responsive so it can resize as per screen size

Tags: html, css, html-table, bootstrap-5

In below html, I'm facing an issue.
when I use bottom scrollbar to scroll from left to right then table go after navbar width as table is wide.
Is there any way to make this table responsive so it can adjust its size accordingly?
So far I tried bootstrap class 'table-responsive' and I also tried css '@media' but it is not helping

Adding snap for visual reference
[image]

```css
//CSS intact with this html
.table {
  padding-top: 0;
}

.table-header {
  border: 1px solid black !important;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

#th {
  width: 30px;
}

.table-data {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  "

}

.table-self {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta content='#000000' name='theme-color' />
  <title>Invoices</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.9/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/inv.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid ps-0">
      <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/brand.png') }}" alt="Priyanshu's Enterprises">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                   </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <div id="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="invoices-header">
        <h1>Invoices</h1>
        <a href="#" id="export-btn">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-file-excel fa-bounce excel-custom"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped my-table ">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 30px;" type="text" placeholder="ID" onkeyup="filterTable(0, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 70px;" type="text" placeholder="Invoice No." onkeyup="filterTable(1, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 80px;" type="date" oninput="updateDate(this.value)"><span id="formatted-date"></span></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Name" onkeyup="filterTable(3, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" placeholder="Email" onkeyup="filterTable(4, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Phone number" onkeyup="filterTable(5, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 90px;" type="text" placeholder="Address" onkeyup="filterTable(6, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 265px;" type="text" placeholder="Items" onkeyup="filterTable(7, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 90px;" type="text" placeholder="Tax" onkeyup="filterTable(8, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Invoice Total" onkeyup="filterTable(9, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Logged by" onkeyup="filterTable(10, this.value)"></th>
            <th class="table-header" style="width: 5px;">Invoice</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for row in rows %}
          <tr>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[0] }}</td>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[1] }}</td>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[2] }}</td>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[3] }}</td>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[4] }}<br><a href="/send_email?id={{ row[0] }}"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-envelope fa-beat-fade email-custom"></i></a></td>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[5] }}<br><a href="https://wa.me/{{ row[5] }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-shake whatsapp-custom"></i></a></td>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[6] }}</td>
            <td class="table-data">
              <table class="table table-striped table-self">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="table-header">Description</th>
                    <th class="table-header">Price</th>
                    <th class="table-header">Qty</th>
                    <th class="table-header">Final Price</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  {% set items = js.loads(row[7]) %} {% for item in items %}
                  <tr>
                    <td class="table-data">{{ item.description }}</td>
                    <td class="table-data">{{ item.price }}</td>
                    <td class="table-data">{{ item.qty }}</td>
                    <td class="table-data">{{ item.final_price }}</td>
                  </tr>
                  {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[8] }}</td>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[9] }}</td>
            <td class="table-data">{{ row[10] }}</td>
            <td class="table-data"><a href="{{ url_for('download', id=row[0]) }}">Download</a></td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="back">
      <a class="back-to-top" onclick="window.scroll(0,0)">BACK TO TOP</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <span class="copyright">
                &copy; Copyright <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> | <a class='copy' href="http://domain.invalid/">Priyanshu</a>
             </span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Don't mix `container-fluid` and `container` in the navbar? And/or replace your main `container-fluid` with `container` and add `overflow: scroll;` to it so that the table doesn't expand. Sounds like you might want to read the documentation.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, I already tried overflow: scroll; and it is working also but table Hight is long and this method will remove the browser X scrollbar and place scrollbar at the bottom of the table on the webpage. I actually want to have x scrollbar of browser with the effect of overflow: scroll;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with below CSS, it is not 100%solution what I want but it is better

```
.table-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 74vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.table{
  padding-top: 0;
}
.table-header {
border: 1px solid black !important;
padding: 10px;
width: 100px;
}

#th {
width: 30px;
}

.table-data{
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
}

.table-self{
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}


div#content, .navbar, #footer {
  padding-right: 15em;  
}

.wrapper {
  width: 115vw;
  
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
   <meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
   <meta content='#000000' name='theme-color' />
   <title>Invoices</title>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.9/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
   <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css'
      crossorigin='anonymous'>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
   <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/inv.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
  
</head>

<body>
   <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-dark">
         <div class="container-fluid ps-0">
            <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                  <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/brand.png') }}" alt="Priyanshu's Enterprises">
               </a>
               <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                  data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                  aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
               </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
               <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contact</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                     <a class="nav-link active" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </nav>
      <br>
      <div id="content">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="invoices-header">
               <h1>Invoices</h1>
               <a href="#" id="export-btn">
                  <i class="fa-solid fa-file-excel fa-bounce excel-custom"></i>
               </a>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="table-responsive">
               <table class="table table-hover table-striped my-table ">
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 30px;" type="text" placeholder="ID"
                              onkeyup="filterTable(0, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 70px;" type="text" placeholder="Invoice No."
                              onkeyup="filterTable(1, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 80px;" type="date"
                              oninput="updateDate(this.value)"><span id="formatted-date"></span></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Name"
                              onkeyup="filterTable(3, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" placeholder="Email"
                              onkeyup="filterTable(4, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Phone number"
                              onkeyup="filterTable(5, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 90px;" type="text" placeholder="Address"
                              onkeyup="filterTable(6, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 265px;" type="text" placeholder="Items"
                              onkeyup="filterTable(7, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 90px;" type="text" placeholder="Tax"
                              onkeyup="filterTable(8, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Invoice Total"
                              onkeyup="filterTable(9, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Logged by"
                              onkeyup="filterTable(10, this.value)"></th>
                        <th class="table-header" style="width: 5px;">Invoice</th>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     {% for row in rows %}
                     <tr>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[0] }}</td>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[1] }}</td>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[2] }}</td>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[3] }}</td>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[4] }}<br><a href="/send_email?id={{ row[0] }}"><i
                                 class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-envelope fa-beat-fade email-custom"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[5] }}<br><a href="https://wa.me/{{ row[5] }}" target="_blank"><i
                                 class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-shake whatsapp-custom"></i></a></td>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[6] }}</td>
                        <td class="table-data">
                           <table class="table table-striped table-self">
                              <thead>
                                 <tr>
                                    <th class="table-header">Description</th>
                                    <th class="table-header">Price</th>
                                    <th class="table-header">Qty</th>
                                    <th class="table-header">Final Price</th>
                                 </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                 {% set items = js.loads(row[7]) %}
                                 {% for item in items %}
                                 <tr>
                                    <td class="table-data">{{ item.description }}</td>
                                    <td class="table-data">{{ item.price }}</td>
                                    <td class="table-data">{{ item.qty }}</td>
                                    <td class="table-data">{{ item.final_price }}</td>
                                 </tr>
                                 {% endfor %}
                              </tbody>
                           </table>
                        </td>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[8] }}</td>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[9] }}</td>
                        <td class="table-data">{{ row[10] }}</td>
                        <td class="table-data"><a href="{{ url_for('download', id=row[0]) }}">Download</a></td>
                     </tr>
                     {% endfor %}
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>

         </div>
      
   </div>
   <div id="footer">
      <div class="back">
         <a class="back-to-top" onclick="window.scroll(0,0)">BACK TO TOP</a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <span class="copyright">
         &copy; Copyright
         <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> | <a class='copy'
            href="http://domain.invalid/">Priyanshu</a>
      </span>
   </div>
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You have to wrap table in one div and add class name "table-responsive" like :

```
<div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table table-hover table-striped my-table ">
        .....
     </table>
</div>
```

because you use bootstrap.

Comment: I tried it and it was working also but table Hight is long and this method will remove the browser X scrollbar and place scrollbar at the bottom of the table on the webpage. I actually want to have x scrollbar of browser with the effect of 'table-responsive'

Comment: I've updated a new snippet if you want something like this.

Comment: i fixed it with below CSS, thanks for your effort,


.table-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 74vh;
  overflow: auto;
}

Answer (score 1):

Add a new div with "table-responsive" class below the  and close it before the  tag like this:

```css
.table{
  padding-top: 0;
}
.table-header {
  border: 1px solid black !important;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}

#th {
  width: 30px;
}

.table-data{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;"
}

.table-self{
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv = "content-language" content = "en">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1 user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta content='#000000' name='theme-color'/>
  <title>Invoices</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.16.9/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css' crossorigin='anonymous'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}">
  <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/script.js') }}"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/inv.ico') }}" type="image/x-icon">
   </head>
   <body >
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  navbar-dark bg-dark">
     <div class="container-fluid ps-0">
        <div class="container d-flex align-items-center">
           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
           <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='img/brand.png') }}" alt="Priyanshu's Enterprises" >
           </a>
           <button class="navbar-toggler ms-auto" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
           </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
           <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                 <a class="nav-link active" href="#">About</a>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
  </nav>
  <br>
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <div id="content">
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="invoices-header">
           <h1>Invoices</h1>
           <a href="#" id="export-btn">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-file-excel fa-bounce excel-custom"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <br>
          <table class="table table-hover table-striped my-table ">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 30px;" type="text" placeholder="ID" onkeyup="filterTable(0, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 70px;" type="text" placeholder="Invoice No." onkeyup="filterTable(1, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 80px;" type="date" oninput="updateDate(this.value)"><span id="formatted-date"></span></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Name" onkeyup="filterTable(3, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 150px;" type="text" placeholder="Email" onkeyup="filterTable(4, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Phone number" onkeyup="filterTable(5, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 90px;" type="text" placeholder="Address" onkeyup="filterTable(6, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 265px;" type="text" placeholder="Items" onkeyup="filterTable(7, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 90px;" type="text" placeholder="Tax" onkeyup="filterTable(8, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Invoice Total" onkeyup="filterTable(9, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header"><input style="width: 60px;" type="text" placeholder="Logged by" onkeyup="filterTable(10, this.value)"></th>
                 <th class="table-header" style="width: 5px;">Invoice</th>
              </tr>
           </thead>
           <tbody>
              {% for row in rows %}
              <tr>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[0] }}</td>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[1] }}</td>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[2] }}</td>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[3] }}</td>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[4] }}<br><a href="/send_email?id={{ row[0] }}"><i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-envelope fa-beat-fade email-custom"></i></a></td>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[5] }}<br><a href="https://wa.me/{{ row[5] }}" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-whatsapp fa-shake whatsapp-custom"></i></a></td>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[6] }}</td>
                 <td class="table-data">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-self">
                       <thead>
                          <tr>
                             <th class="table-header">Description</th>
                             <th class="table-header">Price</th>
                             <th class="table-header">Qty</th>
                             <th class="table-header">Final Price</th>
                          </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                          {% set items = js.loads(row[7]) %}
                          {% for item in items %}
                          <tr>
                             <td class="table-data">{{ item.description }}</td>
                             <td class="table-data">{{ item.price }}</td>
                             <td class="table-data">{{ item.qty }}</td>
                             <td class="table-data">{{ item.final_price }}</td>
                          </tr>
                          {% endfor %}
                       </tbody>
                    </table>
                 </td>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[8] }}</td>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[9] }}</td>
                 <td class="table-data">{{ row[10] }}</td>
                 <td class="table-data"><a href="{{ url_for('download', id=row[0]) }}">Download</a></td>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
           </tbody>
        </table>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
     <div class="back">
        <a class="back-to-top" onclick="window.scroll(0,0)">BACK TO TOP</a>
     </div>
     <br>
     <span class="copyright">
        &copy; Copyright <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear())</script> | <a class='copy' href="http://domain.invalid/">Priyanshu</a>
     </span>
  </div>
 </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it and it is working also but table Hight is long and this method will remove the browser X scrollbar and place scrollbar at the bottom of the table on the webpage. I actually want to have x scrollbar of browser with the effect of 'table-responsive'

Comment: @Priyanshu do you want everything to scroll on the page all together? (like: nav + table + footer)

Comment: @mmirbekian I want the same behavior produced by 'table-responsive' but this will put X scrollbar at the bottom of the table and will remove the browser scrollbar, but I want the scrollbar of the browser instead of scrollbar at bottom of the table while keeping table responsive

Comment: @Priyanshu I have edited the code. Let me know if this is what you need.